# Is there a Spring analog for @RunAs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In JEE there is `@RunAs("role_name")` annotation, that allows to invoke application methods under a particular role.

Is there a `@RunAs` analog in Spring?
If there is no equivalent annotations, which are other ways to invoke methods with some role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the spring [RunAsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/runas.html) then annotate your method with `@Secured("RUN_AS_<MY_ROLE>")`, where `<MY_ROLE>` is the role you wish to execute the method as.

The key here is the prefix `RUN_AS`. It triggers the run as logic to add the suffixed role.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Security, you can use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE')")` as:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> getAllUserByRole(...) {
    }
```

What it is saying is, this particular method can be invoked by only user with ROLE either `SUPER_ADMIN` or `ADMIN`.

Comment: But isn't it just a way to **secure** the method with this role? Because I need the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a quick solution of adding a custom user into security context.
Since I need this for invoking secured service methods in Kafka listener class, that is not affected by any authentication process by itself.

```
User user = new User("SYSTEM", "SYSTEM", "SYSTEM");
UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl(user, 
Arrays.asList(<YOUR_ROLE_HERE>)); 
// UserDetailsImpl - class that implements 
// org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
```